# Exception Value: 'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: django, django-models

, Exception Value:    'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function,Exception Value:    'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function,Exception Value:    'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function,Exception Value:    'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function,Exception Value:    'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function,Exception Value:    'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function, Exception Value:   'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function,Exception Value:    'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function,Exception Value:    'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function,Exception Value:    'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function,Exception Value:    'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function,Exception Value:    'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
    views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from student.models import Student
from student.serializers import StudentSerializer


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def Student_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = Student.objects.all()
        serializer = Student(Student, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = Student(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def Student_detail(request, pk):

    try:
        snippet = Student.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Student.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = Student(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = Student(snippet, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        snippet.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

models.py

from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    fname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cnt=models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        ordering=('id',)

serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from student.models import Student

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields=('id','fname','lname','cnt')

        def create (self,validated_data):
            return Student.objects.create(**validated_data)

        def update(self,instance,validated_data):
            instance.id=validated_data.get('id',instance.id)
            instance.fname=validated_data.get('fname',instance.fname)
            instance.lname=validated_data.get('lname',instance.lname)
            instance.cnt=validated_data.get('cnt',instance.cnt)
            instance.save()
            return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Student_list` view you need to replace `serializer = Student(Student, many=True)` with `serializer = StudentSerializer(snippets, many=True)`:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    snippets = Student.objects.all()
    serializer = StudentSerializer(snippets, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

`Sudent` is model class, but for serialization you need to use serializer class and pass to it Student instance or Student queryset.